# Angular - TypeError: path must be a string for $scope.formData?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a form that has a number field:

```
input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0" ng-model="formData.position"
```

And when I submit the form, the .error function responds with the 500 Internal Server Error, Error: TypeError: path must be a string

```
$scope.createProduct = function() {

        // validate the formData (using our exentions.js .filter) to make sure that something is there
        //if form is empty, nothing will happen
        if (!isEmptyObjectFilter($scope.formData)) {

                // call the create function from our service (returns a promise object)
                Emotions.create($scope.formData)

                        // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new emotions
                        .success(function(data) {
                                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                                $scope.products = data; // assign our new list of emotions
                        })
                        .error(function(data) {
                                console.log('Error: ' + data);
                        });
        }
};
```

Can formData be a mix of strings and integers?

Here's the create line in the Service:

```
    create : function(emotionData) {
        return $http.post('/api/emotions', emotionData);
    },
```

I have a Mongoose schema that looks like this:

```
var ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    position: Number
});
```

The stack trace for the error looks like this:

```
TypeError: path must be a string
    at Query.where (/Users/KK/Downloads/awaken/v16/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:593:11)
    at Function.where (/Users/KK/Downloads/awaken/v16/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1040:18)
    at model.<anonymous> (/Users/KK/Downloads/awaken/v16/app/models/emotion.js:44:35)
...
```

Which looks to lead to this line (44?) of the emotion.js file:

```
mongoose.model("Product").where({_id: {$ne: doc._id}, position: doc.position}).count( function (err, count) {
```

And this is what I was posting about here:

[Increment field on all records in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899431/increment-field-on-all-records-in-mongo)

Comment: As the error message says "`path` must be a string." You appear to be looking for your problem in the wrong place. You should look at the stack trace. The problem is more likely related to a file access attempt.

Comment: @barry-johnson Where would I look/test? Creation works when I leave the number field blank..

Comment: Are you getting any kind of stack trace in (e.g.) your console output? You show the client side code, but you don't show what you are doing on the server to handle the request or even your angular resource/service code, or indicate what server communication takes place prior to the error.

Comment: @barry-johnson added the stack trace, and some more info.. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not a Mongo guy so probably won't be of much use in the specifics of that. I'd fire up a debugger and step through what's happening on the server side of your request, since that seems to be the source of the error.